# Using WiX, how can I install a file into a new user profile that I also have to create?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm developing a WiX installer. Part of the process is to create a new user and add that user to the local admins group. I'm doing this with a `<User>` element like so:

```
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <util:Group Id="grpLocalAdmins" Name="Administrators" />
    <ComponentGroup Id="cgUserAccounts" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="cmpUserAccounts" Guid="my-guid" >
        <util:User Id="user"
                   CreateUser="yes"
                   Name="new-user-name"
                   Password="[PASSWORD]"
                   PasswordNeverExpires="yes"
                   RemoveOnUninstall="yes"
                   UpdateIfExists="yes"
                   Vital="yes">
          <util:GroupRef Id="grpLocalAdmins" />
        </util:User>
        <CreateFolder Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

Having done that, I need to create a directory in the user's profile and then place a configuration file in that folder.

How can I achieve this, given that the user profile doesn't already exist?